# Generic way to convert String to Object

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I am implementing a Utility method that accept String as parameter and convert to object with generic. I can achieve with the code below but the **weak point** is *every object that need to parse must have a string constructor*. There is no way of defining that the object must have String constructor. Is there any other better way to achieve this by Using polymorphism or generic?

**AAA.java**

```
public class AAA {
    private String id;
    private String description;

    public AAA(String str) {
        // Do parsing... 
    }
```

**Utility method.**

```
public static <T extends Base> List<T> readFile(File file, Class<T> type) {
    List<T> collection = new ArrayList<T>();
    // Read file line by line and convert to Instance

    Constructor<T> ctor = type.getConstructor(String.class);
    T newInstance = ctor.newInstance(line);
    if (newInstance != null) {
        collection.add(newInstance);
    }   
    return collection;
}
```

Usage:

```
List<AAA> list = FileUtil.readFile(file, AAA.class);
```

Comment: What format is your string in? Or rather your file. Is it CSV comma delimited or is it in JSON or something like that.

Comment: Are you the one to decide the format of the string?

Comment: @DanielvanHeerden it is CSV.

Comment: @swemon If I understand well, you would like the compiler to enforce that the `Class<T> type` argument of your `readFile` method has a constructor which accepts a `String` as its only argument, right?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your POJO classes (the one which actually contain the data) are usually in the format you have in your example. Meaning all the fields are `String` values. If this is not the case my solution needs a little bit of refinement.

My suggestion is to use reflection for the use case you describe. I have been very successful with this in the past. Although reflection can pose severe performance penalties if applied badly.

Parsing code could look roughly like the following. I omit a method header since the one you provide already looks good. The code I provide will assume that in the `String[]` variable `line` we find an already parsed line of your CSV file. Each element of the array containing one column of the CSV line.

```
String[] line; // initialised as explained above
T newInstance = T.newInstance(); // invoke default constructor
Field[] fields = newInstance.getClass().getDeclaredFields(); // use reflection to read all fields
int count = 0;
for(Fields f : fields) {
    f.set(newInstance, line[count]);
    count++;
}
```

Disclaimer: The above code does not do any boundary checks! The assumption is that the CSV lines and the number of fields in a class have the same length!

On the `Field` objects what I usually do is to also call `getAnnotation` to check whether or not a certain annotation is set on the field. This allows you to write classes like that:

```
public class AAAAnnotated {

    @MyCSVAnnotation
    String field1;

    @MyCSVAnnotation
    String field2;

    String field3;
}
```

If your code checks whether or not fields are annotated with your annotations you can even control in the POJO classes which fields to load form CSV and which to leave untouched.